# Assign multiple data types value to one variable has any effect of performance and memory?

Tags: javascript

e.g.

```js
var tmp = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2"
};                              // Object
tmp = JSON.stringify(tmp);              // String
tmp = tmp.split(',');                 // Array
tmp = tmp[0]                       // String
tmp = tmp.split(':')                 // Array

.
.
.
   }
```

I have assign multiple data types to the same variable 'tmp'.
I want to know does this has any effects?

Comment: no not really, js is a dynamic type language.

Comment: No, but generally, it is a sign of poorly designed code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has a detrimental effect on performance.

- The JS engine's optimising compiler can't infer the type and needs to create less efficient code
- The developer can't infer the type and has a harder time understanding the code